# Cordova app stuck on splash screen on iOS 14 Beta

Tags: cordova, ios14, cordova-ios

I have a plain Cordova app and when I run it on iOS 14 beta the app gets stuck on the splash screen and there are few warnings/errors logged in XCode but I am not sure whether it is causing the problem.

I have created a blank Cordova app to test whether it works on iOS 14 and when I run it on the device the app worked as expected but when I set the app to use **WKWebView** instead of **UIWebView** the app got stuck on the splash screen.

I have added the below preferences to use the WKWebView in config.xml file.

```
<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>
```

I have also added the cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine but I do not know whether it helped me to set the WKWebView.

Below is the error I get in XCode:

```
2020-08-17 12:01:37.990216+0530 BankWindhoek[58947:1465531] nil host used in call to allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:
2020-08-17 12:01:37.991180+0530 BankWindhoek[58947:1465531] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
```

But after getting this error the XCode prints the statement that it has loaded the index.html

```
2020-08-17 12:01:38.039671+0530 BankWindhoek[58947:1465275] Finished load of: file:///Users/user1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/88FDF8E3-EDCE-4BB6-95B3-29CA606DA2C5/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/6EE35C46-E78E-4E49-B836-17EBDE6CD664/test.app/www/index.html
```

But on the UI of the app, nothing renders properly and shows a blank white screen.

**Configurations**:

Cordova Version: 9.0.0

Cordova-ios: 5.1.1

**Note**: If I run the same app on iOS 13/iOS 13.1 it worked as expected.

Answer (score 4):

You should upgrade to Cordova 10 and then remove

```
<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>
```

and remove

```
 cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine
```

Then

```
 cordova plugin add @globules-io/cordova-plugin-ios-xhr
```

and setup the flags like you would for wkwebview-engine.

You also have to upgrade your splashscreen plugin for the new splashscreen image format. Read https://cordova.apache.org/news/2020/07/21/splashscreen-plugin-release.html

Comment: the cordova plugin ```@globules-io/cordova-plugin-ios-xhr``` doesnt install on cordova-ios 5.1.1

Comment: Splashscreen is not compatible with 5.1.1 and iOS14. You need to use codova-ios 6+, read the link I posted

Comment: cordova-plugin-ios-xhr is installing cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine, if your version of cordova is > 6.0.0, the build will fail.

Comment: Julie, it's not, it a fork for ios 6+